# Saving only one value in preferences file - libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, save, sharedpreferences, flush

I would like to save the player's best score in the game's preferences file. Now, I know I need to call the flush() method in order for the values to get persisted, but I have other values( options) such as "music on/off" and "sound on/off" which I don't want to get saved at all.

So my question is - how can I save only the best score value without saving the other ones?

Comment: Ummm, if you do not want to persist them, why do you manage them via `Preferences`?

Comment: I also don't understand, why you don't want to persist changes on values you manage via `Preferences`. Anyways, it is possible to have multiple `Preferences` for one game, so just use another `Preference` for the Highscores.

Answer (score 0):

this a simple test
 ..//

```
float score = "your score player actual";

float bestScore = YourPreferences.getFloat("BestScore", -1);

if(bestScore < score){

 YourPreferences.putFloat("BestScore", score).flush();

}
```

Comment: I know how to save a value and flush it but I have another 2 values which I don't want to get persisted. How do I save this one value without saving the other two?

Comment: @David Lasry Now, I ask you a question to you, how can you have asked 48 questions and you've just given a positive vote? I think you should think about it